# VBA delete rows after table

Tags: mysql, vba, excel, macros

I have a spreadsheet in excel 2010 with a macro that resizes a table (table 1) based upon the size of another table (table 2), as they should always have the same number of rows.  The number of rows in table 2 changes on a montly basis.  This macro works fine as long as table 2 is adding rows.  If table 2 is subtracting rows, then I wind up with formulas / data under table 1 that is unneeded.  Macro I'm using:

```
Sub Table 1()
    Sheet3.Unprotect Password:="password"
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").ListObjects("Table 1").Resize [range]
        Sheet3.Protect Password:="password"
    End Sub
```

Is there a way to write a Macro to remove this extraneous data (all data / formulas after the current table)?  I know it's a simple matter to delete them manually, but I'm hoping to protect the tab containing table one, and only allow macros (that will also be protected) to run, to avoid random people messing with this worksheet.  Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks!
Graham

Comment: What does this have to do with MySql?

Comment: Is Table 1 only formulas? If there's data in Table 1, how does it get in there?

Comment: I guess nothing to do with mysql, needed 5 tags and system suggested.  Table one is only formulas.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the number of rows before resizing and then after resizing. Then, delete the difference rows if your table got smaller. In my example, my table is named `Table1`, so you need to make a couple edits. Give the following a try.

[image: CRUTER example of short resizing table issue]

```
Sub test()

Dim rowsBefore As Integer
Dim rowsAfter As Integer
Dim rowsExtra As Integer

'get num of rows before resize
rowsBefore = Range("Table1").Rows.Count

'resize table
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").ListObjects("Table 1").Resize [range]

'get num of rows after resize
rowsAfter = Range("Table1").Rows.Count

'get num of rows removed / added
rowsExtra = rowsBefore - rowsAfter

'remove data if positive / removed rows
If rowsExtra > 0 Then
    Range("Table1[testColumn]")(rowsAfter + 1).Select
    Range(ActiveCell.Address, ActiveCell.Offset(1 + rowsExtra).Address).EntireRow.Delete
End If

End Sub
```